# Combine multiple result rows into one in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT [Course Section], [Instructor Name], [Respondent Code], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM [sirssoctonlineforms].[dbo].[Denormalized_V]
where term = 'ss14' and subject = 'iss' and course like '%330%'
order by subject, course, [course section], [respondent code]
```

And the results are:

```
Respondent Code     1         2              3              4              5
1281172             Average   Above Average  Above Average  Above Average  NULL
1281172             NULL      NULL           NULL           NULL           Average
```

What I want to see is this:

```
Respondent Code     1         2              3              4              5
1281172             Average   Above Average  Above Average  Above Average  Average
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: where are the `[Course Section], [Instructor Name]` columns in your results?

Comment: is it possible that for some column (let's say for column [3]) there is a non-null value in more than one row?

Comment: The results are pretty much two rows for each respondent code and the nulls will always be in the same columns.  It's basically the responses for a set of questions for a class, the first few pertain to the instructor and the rest are about the class as a whole.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [Course Section], [Instructor Name], [Respondent Code], 
       max([1]) as [1], 
       max([2]) as [2], 
       max([3]) as [3], 
       max([4]) as [4], 
       max([5]) as [5]
FROM [sirssoctonlineforms].[dbo].[Denormalized_V]
where term = 'ss14' and subject = 'iss' and course like '%330%'
group by [Course Section], [Instructor Name], [Respondent Code]
order by subject, course, [course section], [respondent code]
```

Comment: @JosephB Not my downvote, but without seeing the values for the other columns, we have no way of knowing if this query would work

Comment: @Lamak I think I agree. It might be put the original query in a subquery and then do max.